# Phonegap 3.3.0 iOS FileSystem plugin not firing complete, progress or error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to use the FileTransfer plugin on iOS with Phonegap 3.3.0.  It has been working in my app in the past, but since I updated all my libraries JQuery (1.11.0), JQuery Mobile(1.4.1) I am not getting any callbacks associated with the file transfers.

I know the files are downloading, because I can see them appear on the filesystem in the iOS Simulator temporary files, etc.  Furthermore, they seem to have completed downloading as the files appear complete.

My code:

```
function download(url, dest, cb) {

    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    console.log("remote:"+url+" local:"+dest);

    fileTransfer.onprogress = progress;
    fileTransfer.download(url, dest, downloadSuccess, fail);
}
function progress() {
    console.log("progress:"+arguments);
}
function fail() {
    console.log("fail:"+arguments);
}
function downloadSuccess() {
    console.log("download complete: " + arguments);
}
```

Any thoughts about what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap 3.3.0's Filesystem has a new approach. If you have been using fullpath for entry, you need to replace that with toURL().

Also in your config.xml file you got to add

```
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

Your best bet would be to go over this link https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/dev/doc/index.md

Making these changes worked for me. Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I think your callbacks are fired but you have syntax errors because you try to use `arguments` parameter but do not define it.

Also, as the callbacks take objects, using arguments in the console.log, it will only display 'object'. You should either stringify it or use a property of the object.

for example:

```
function download(url, dest, cb) {

    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    console.log("remote:"+url+" local:"+dest);

    fileTransfer.onprogress = progress;
    fileTransfer.download(url, dest, downloadSuccess, fail);
}
function progress(arguments) {
    console.log("progress:"+Math.floor(100*arguments.loaded/arguments.total)+"%");
}
function fail(arguments) {
    console.log("fail error code:"+arguments.code);
}
function downloadSuccess(arguments) {
    console.log("download complete: " + arguments.bytesSent + " bytes sent");
}
```

Comment: Inside every JavaScript functions you have access to the `arguments` array which contains (you gessed it) the *arguments* which were received by the function being called.  So that's not the problem. Apache has this same bug registered in their bug tracking system (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9936). So it's really a bug in Phonegap/Cordova filetransfer plugin. I just don't know if there's already a solution for it or if we can only use the workaround explained in the issue.